# Finding bounded nearest neighbour in a 1-dimensional array

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, computer-science, complexity-theory

Let's say we have some array of boolean values:

```
A = [0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ... 0]
```

The array is constructed by performing classification on a stream of data. Each element in the array corresponds to the output of a classification algorithm given a small "chunk" of the data. An answer may include restructuring the array to make parsing more efficient.

The array is pseudo random in the sense that groups of `1`'s and `0`'s tend to exist in bunches (but not necessarily always).

**Given some index, `i`, what is the most efficient way to find the group of at least `n` zeros closest to `A[i]`? For the easy case, take `n = 1`.**

EDIT: Groups should have **AT LEAST** n zeros. Again, for the easy case, that means at least 1 zero.

EDIT2: This search will be performed `o(n)` times, where `n` is size of the array. (Specifically, its `n/c`, where `c` is some fixed duration.

Comment: should the required group have exactly N zeroes or N+ zeroes is also acceptable?

Comment: Must the group have exactly `n`, or at least `n`? Do you expect to perform this search many times, would it be best to do some pre-processing for an initial efficiency hit but much better efficiency on the searches? What sizes can we expect the array to be? Efficiency can be very context sensitive.

Comment: Updated the post. Groups should have at least n

Comment: Does `n` change while you're streaming? Or do you expect to have the same `n` throughout the streaming? I assume you'd like an online algorithm, or are you interested in a post-processing structure to provide optimal query performance for arbitrary `i` and `n`?

Comment: For all intents and purposes you can consider it post processing. `n` is defined outside the solution. The solution should be able to work with any `i` and any `n`. There are edge cases like, `n < i` that you don't necessarily need to consider for a working solution. I'm more interested in the process used to get there.

Comment: Starting from index i, you can go in both direction at the same time, going left and right by 1 index every time, so i-1, i+1, i-2, i+2, ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have n queries on an array of size n, then the naive approach would take O(n^2) time.

You can optimize this by incorporating the observation that the number of distinct group sizes is in the order of sqrt(n), because the most distinct group sizes we get if we have one group of size 1, one of size 2, one of size 3 and so on, we know that 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n is n * (n + 1) / 2, so in the order of n^2, but the array has size n, so the number of distinct group sizes is in the order of sqrt(n).

1. create an integer array of size n to denote which group sizes are present how many times
2. create a list for the 0-groups, each element should contain the group size and starting index
3. scan the array, add the 0-groups to the list and update the present group sizes
4. create an array for the different group sizes, each entry should contain the group size and an array with the start indices of the groups
5. create an integer array or a map which tells you which group size is at which index by scanning the array of the present group sizes
6. go through the list of 0-groups and fill the start index arrays created at 4.

We end up with an array which takes O(n) space, takes O(n) time to create and contains all present group sizes in order, additionally each entry has an array with the start indices of the groups of that size.

To answer a query we can do a binary search on the start indices of all groups greater or equal than the given minimum group size. This takes O(log(n)*sqrt(n)) and we do it n times, so over all it would take `O(n*log(n)*sqrt(n)) = O(n^1.5*log(n))` which is better than O(n^2).

I think you can get it down to O(n^1.5) by creating a structure which has all distinct group sizes but contains not only the groups of that size, but also the groups that are bigger than that size. This would be the time complexity to create the structure and answering all the n queries would be faster O(n*log(sqrt(n))*log(n)) I think, so it doesn't matter.

example:

```
[0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0, 1, 0, 0]   -- 0 indexed array

hashmap = {1:[0], 2:[15, 18], 7:[5]}

search(i = 7, n = 2) {
   binary search in {2:[15, 18], 7:[5]}
   return min(15, 5)
}
```

Comment: It's interesting to see the different ways to approach a problem. You are clearly quite clever with algorithms. Mind having a look at my solution to see if there is room for improvement *or correcting my time/space complexity*? I think my solution is pretty good but I'd love a second opinion and constructive criticism.

Comment: @xtratic I think this is the same as what I proposed as 2nd solution. My reasoning for it being O(n^1.5) is that you have to add O(n) groups to at most O(sqrt(n)) distinct group sizes, shouldn't be worse than that, but could be better.

Comment: Ahh, I thought the second part of your answer sounded similar. You're right, by how you describe it, I could cut down on the number of lists of groups in my `GroupsBySize` to only have a list per distinct group size. I'll edit my answer tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution I organize the data so that you can use a binary search `O(log n)` to find the nearest group of at least a certain size.

I first create groups of zeros from the array, then I put each group of zeros into lists containing all groups of size `s` or larger , so that when you want to find the nearest group of s `s` or more then you just run a binary search in the list that has all groups with a size of `s` or greater.

The downside is in the pre-processing of putting the groups into the lists, with `O(n * m)` *(I think, please check me)* time and space efficiency where `n` is the number of groups of zeros, and `m` is the max size of the groups, though in reality the efficiency is probably better.

Here is the code:

---

```
public static class Group {
    final public int x1;
    final public int x2;
    final public int size;

    public Group(int x1, int x2) {
        assert x1 <= x2;
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.size = x2 - x1 + 1;
    }

    public static final List<Group> getGroupsOfZeros(byte[] arr) {
        List<Group> listOfGroups = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == 0) {
                int x1 = i;
                for (++i; i < arr.length; i++)
                    if (arr[i] != 0)
                        break;
                int x2 = i - 1;
                listOfGroups.add(new Group(x1, x2));
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(listOfGroups);
    }

    public static final Group binarySearchNearest(int i, List<Group> list) {
        { // edge cases
            Group firstGroup = list.get(0);
            if (i <= firstGroup.x2)
                return firstGroup;
            Group lastGroup = list.get(list.size() - 1);
            if (i >= lastGroup.x1)
                return lastGroup;
        }
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = list.size() - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = (hi + lo) / 2;
            Group currGroup = list.get(mid);
            if (i < currGroup.x1) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else if (i > currGroup.x2) {
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else {
                // x1 <= i <= x2
                return currGroup;
            }
        }

        // intentionally swapped because: lo == hi + 1
        Group lowGroup = list.get(hi);
        Group highGroup = list.get(lo);
        return (i - lowGroup.x2) < (highGroup.x1 - i) ? lowGroup : highGroup;
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE:** `GroupsBySize` can be improved, as described by @maraca to only contain a list of `Group`s per each distinct group size. I'll update tomorrow.

```
public static class GroupsBySize {
    private List<List<Group>> listOfGroupsBySize = new ArrayList<>();

    public GroupsBySize(List<Group> groups) {
        for (Group group : groups) {
            // ensure internal array can groups up to this size
            while (listOfGroupsBySize.size() < group.size) {
                listOfGroupsBySize.add(new ArrayList<Group>());
            }
            // add group to all lists up to its size
            for (int i = 0; i < group.size; i++) {
                listOfGroupsBySize.get(i).add(group);
            }
        }
    }

    public final Group getNearestGroupOfAtLeastSize(int index, int atLeastSize) {
        if (atLeastSize < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("group size must be greater than 0");
        List<Group> groupsOfAtLeastSize = listOfGroupsBySize.get(atLeastSize - 1);
        return Group.binarySearchNearest(index, groupsOfAtLeastSize);
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] byteArray = null;

    List<Group> groups = Group.getGroupsOfZeros(byteArray);
    GroupsBySize groupsBySize = new GroupsBySize(groups);

    int index = 12;
    int atLeastSize = 5;
    Group g = groupsBySize.getNearestGroupOfAtLeastSize(index, atLeastSize);

    System.out.println("nearest group is (" + g.x1 + ":" + g.x2 + ") of size " + g.size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what is the most efficient way to find the group of at least n zeros closest to A[i]

If we are not limited in preprocessing time and resources, the most efficient way would seem to be `O(1)` time and `O(n * sqrt n)` space, storing the answers to all possible queries. (To accomplish that, run the algorithm below with a list of all possible queries, that is each distinct zero-group size in the array paired with each index.)

If we are provided with all the `n / c` queries at once, we can produce the complete result set in `O(n log n)` time.

Traverse once from the left and once from the right. For each traversal, start with a balanced binary tree with our queries, sorted by zero-group-size (the `n` in the query), where each node has a sorted list of the query indexes (all `i`s with this particular `n`).

At each iteration, when a zero-group is registered, update all queries with `n` equal and lower than this zero-group size, removing all equal and lower indexes from the node and keeping the records for them (since the index list is sorted, we just remove the head of the list while it's equal or lower than the current index), and storing the current index of the zero-group in the node as well (the "last seen" zero-group-index). If no `i`s are left in the node, remove it.

After the traversal, assign each node's "last seen" zero-group-index to any remaining `i`s in that node. Now we have all the answers for this traversal. (Any queries left in the tree have no answer.) In the opposite traversal, if any query comes up with a better (closer) answer, update it in the final record.